# How to Show Interstitial Ad every X Seconds

Tags: android, android-studio, ads, interstitial

I need to show interstitial ad in my app in every x seconds. I had gated this code. Its working fine, but the problem is, interstitial ads still show up even if the app closed.

How can I can stop this when the app is closed?

Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prepareAd();

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("hello", "world");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                           Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                        }

                        prepareAd();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void  prepareAd() {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your activity is in background and then user will be able to see the ads because once your activity is destroyed then your ads won't be able to display , no `this` context no activity.

First : keep a reference to `ScheduledExecutorService` outside `onCreate`

Second : Override `onStop` and invoke `scheduler.shutdownNow()`.

`onStop` : it will be invoked when your activity will go into the background state

`shutdownNow()` : will attempts to stop currently running tasks and stop the execution of waiting tasks

so this will stop the executor even if your app is in background

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private boolean isVisible;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prepareAd();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
        isVisible = true;
        if(scheduler == null){
            scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("hello", "world");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() && isVisible) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                       Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                    }

                    prepareAd();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

    }    
    //.. code 

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
        scheduler = null;
        isVisible =false;
   }

}
```

Comment: not fixed .. if there is a solution to make a button to exit from app and stop the ads that will be good   Thanks

Comment: @RedOne might be possible that scheduler is not able to cancel pending tasks, try the updated code, it will show the ads only when activity is visible

Comment: Solved :) Thanks